# How does one run Google refine on a different port than 3333?

Tags: openrefine

By default, google refine listens on port 3333.  How does one start it on a different port?

[There some other process that has taken up 3333 and I cannot change that]

Update: Running this on a Mac (10.8.x)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./refine -p 9999
```

From the documentation: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Thanks.  I should have specified that I'm running this on a Mac.  Tried to no avail `/Applications/Google\ Refine.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub -p 9999`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a different port on the command line.

```
./refine -p <port>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you edit /Applications/Google Refine.app/Contents/Info.plist

and replace

```
  <string>-Xms256M -Xmx4096M -Drefine.version=r2407</string>
```

with

```
  <string>-Xms256M -Xmx4096M -Drefine.version=r2407 -Drefine.port=5555</string>
```

(or whatever port number you need instead of 5555) this should work.

Adapted from the bottom of the OpenRefine instructions page: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Installation-Instructions